# Woocommerce orders not showing up in dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem. I got a order in woocommerce. when I search the order(Customer name) name for filter it's showing but when i click to filter button then I can''t see the order.
please help me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.